# Google Play Pre-launch report and AdMob

Tags: android, react-native, admob, ads, prelaunch

Some time ago there was a problem: your AdMob account could get suspended if you enable pre-launch report in app with AdMob ads. It's because clicks during creating report where detected as your own.

Do I (in 2022) still need to handle AdMob with Pre-launch report in my mobile app or it works out of the box. Source: https://ubuverse.com/using-admob-in-your-android-app-beware-of-the-pre-launch-report/

Comment: Do you have an answer to this question? I got "Ad serving is limited" problem for my new published app. Before publishing, I created "internal testing" track.

Comment: I still don't know answer but I found way to turn off ads during Pre-launch report. I use `utils().isRunningInTestLab`, check it here https://rnfirebase.io/app/utils#test-lab